# 'Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?'

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I'm working on an application where I've been trying to figure out the best way to bulk update (or do a large chunk post to a Postgres server using knex).

For some reason now, I cannot get any data to load in my database and I really have no clue where to look to fix this issue.

This was what I was working on last (using batchInsert instead of insert), and attempted to upload one bulk JSON object of around 9000 rows.

```
  //create new asset in the system
  const chunkSize = 12000;
  const result = !Array.isArray(req.body.data) ? { //stringify single asset history into json array
    ...req.body.data, history: JSON.stringify(req.body.data.history)
  } : req.body.data.map(data => {return {...data, history: JSON.stringify(data.history)}}); //stringify each bulk asset's history into json array
  const data = await knex
    // .insert(result)
    .batchInsert('assets', result, chunkSize)
    .returning("*")
    .then((results) => results[0]); //return result
  res.status(201).json({ data });
}
```

...and it seems like now, all I get is the following error:

```
'Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?'
```

Even when I restart my server, I still can't get any data to load. I've used dBeaver and my assets table never loads. I realize this may seem somewhat vague, but I'm newer to this and have no clue how or where I broke this, but I need to figure out what I did and need to fix this.

This is also part of my server code:

```
// app.use(express.json()); //express server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "100mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'})); //express server
app.use(cors()); //cross orgin reference sharing
```